# Makefile issue. Second set of eyes please

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
PROJ     =      .
SRC_ROOT =      .
FLAGS    =      -g -Wall -Wextra

INC      =      -I$(PROJ)                               \
                -I$(SRC_ROOT)/Exception                 \
                -I$(SRC_ROOT)/MapFile

DEPS     =      $(SRC_ROOT)/Exception/Exception.h       \
                $(SRC_ROOT)/Exception/Exception.cpp     \
                $(SRC_ROOT)/MapFile/MapFile.h           \
                $(SRC_ROOT)/MapFile/MapFile.cpp

OBJS     =      $(SRC_ROOT)/MapFile/MapFIle.o           \
                $(SRC_ROOT)/Exception/Exception.o

all: main $(OBJS)

%.o : %.cpp %.h
        g++ -c $(FLAGS) $(INC) $< -o $@

main: $(DEPS) $(OBJS) main.cpp
        g++ -o main $(FLAGS) $(INC) main.cpp $(OBJS)

$(SRC_ROOT)/MapFile/MapFIle.o : $(SRC_ROOT)/MapFile/MapFIle.cpp $(SRC_ROOT)/MapFile/MapFIle.h
        g++ -c $(FLAGS) $(INC) $< -o $@


clean:
        rm -f *~
        rm -f $(OBJS)
        rm -f main
        rm -f -R *.dSYM
```

When I comment out the explicit rule for MapFile.o I get a "no rule to build error for it" yet the implicit rule clearly works for Exception.o. Any idea what could be the issue? Hope it is not something simple that I am missing having been staring at it for a few. Thanks in advance.

Using GNU Make 3.81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filenames are case-sensitive; in some places you have `MapFile.cpp` and `MapFile.h`, but elsewhere you have `MapFIle.o` (with a capital `I`) and `MapFIle.cpp` and so on.

Comment: Thats what it is. I should have been able to catch that one myself. matter of my eyes tricking me. Thanks for the second set of eyes.